Buy Sell condition not showing required logic
I have done some changes in the Buy and Sell signal logic in the original tradingview script
SuperTrended Moving Averages
I want buy when trend is UP and candle open below mPlot (Blue Line) on the chart and candle close above mPlot. and exactly opposite for Sell trend is Down and candle is open above mPlot line and close below mPlot line.
My chart TF is 5m and indicator TF is 15m.
Below is my edited code:
//@version=5

indicator('SuperTrended Moving Averages', 'ST MA', overlay=true, format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe='15', timeframe_gaps=false)
src = input(close, title='Source')
mav = input.string(title='Moving Average Type', defval='HULL', options=['SMA', 'EMA', 'WMA', 'DEMA', 'TMA', 'VAR', 'WWMA', 'ZLEMA', 'TSF', 'HULL', 'TILL'])
length = input.int(150, 'Moving Average Length', minval=1)
Periods = input(title='ATR Period', defval=10)
Multiplier = input.float(title='ATR Multiplier', step=0.1, defval=0.5)
changeATR = input(title='Change ATR Calculation Method ?', defval=true)
showsignals = input(title='Show Buy/Sell Signals ?', defval=false)
highlighting = input(title='Highlighter On/Off ?', defval=true)



T3a1 = input.float(0.7, 'TILLSON T3 Volume Factor', step=0.1)


Var_Func(src, length) =>
    valpha = 2 / (length + 1)
    vud1 = src > src[1] ? src - src[1] : 0
    vdd1 = src < src[1] ? src[1] - src : 0
    vUD = math.sum(vud1, 9)
    vDD = math.sum(vdd1, 9)
    vCMO = nz((vUD - vDD) / (vUD + vDD))
    VAR = 0.0
    VAR := nz(valpha * math.abs(vCMO) * src) + (1 - valpha * math.abs(vCMO)) * nz(VAR[1])
    VAR
VAR = Var_Func(src, length)
DEMA = 2 * ta.ema(src, length) - ta.ema(ta.ema(src, length), length)
Wwma_Func(src, length) =>
    wwalpha = 1 / length
    WWMA = 0.0
    WWMA := wwalpha * src + (1 - wwalpha) * nz(WWMA[1])
    WWMA
WWMA = Wwma_Func(src, length)
Zlema_Func(src, length) =>
    zxLag = length / 2 == math.round(length / 2) ? length / 2 : (length - 1) / 2
    zxEMAData = src + src - src[zxLag]
    ZLEMA = ta.ema(zxEMAData, length)
    ZLEMA
ZLEMA = Zlema_Func(src, length)
Tsf_Func(src, length) =>
    lrc = ta.linreg(src, length, 0)
    lrc1 = ta.linreg(src, length, 1)
    lrs = lrc - lrc1
    TSF = ta.linreg(src, length, 0) + lrs
    TSF
TSF = Tsf_Func(src, length)
HMA = ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(src, length / 2) - ta.wma(src, length), math.round(math.sqrt(length)))
T3e1 = ta.ema(src, length)
T3e2 = ta.ema(T3e1, length)
T3e3 = ta.ema(T3e2, length)
T3e4 = ta.ema(T3e3, length)
T3e5 = ta.ema(T3e4, length)
T3e6 = ta.ema(T3e5, length)
T3c1 = -T3a1 * T3a1 * T3a1
T3c2 = 3 * T3a1 * T3a1 + 3 * T3a1 * T3a1 * T3a1
T3c3 = -6 * T3a1 * T3a1 - 3 * T3a1 - 3 * T3a1 * T3a1 * T3a1
T3c4 = 1 + 3 * T3a1 + T3a1 * T3a1 * T3a1 + 3 * T3a1 * T3a1
T3 = T3c1 * T3e6 + T3c2 * T3e5 + T3c3 * T3e4 + T3c4 * T3e3


getMA(src, length) =>
    ma = 0.0
    if mav == 'SMA'
        ma := ta.sma(src, length)
        ma

    if mav == 'EMA'
        ma := ta.ema(src, length)
        ma

    if mav == 'WMA'
        ma := ta.wma(src, length)
        ma

    if mav == 'DEMA'
        ma := DEMA
        ma

    if mav == 'TMA'
        ma := ta.sma(ta.sma(src, math.ceil(length / 2)), math.floor(length / 2) + 1)
        ma

    if mav == 'VAR'
        ma := VAR
        ma

    if mav == 'WWMA'
        ma := WWMA
        ma

    if mav == 'ZLEMA'
        ma := ZLEMA
        ma

    if mav == 'TSF'
        ma := TSF
        ma

    if mav == 'HULL'
        ma := HMA
        ma

    if mav == 'TILL'
        ma := T3
        ma
    ma

MA = getMA(src, length)



atr2 = ta.sma(ta.tr, Periods)
atr = changeATR ? ta.atr(Periods) : atr2
up = MA - Multiplier * atr
up1 = nz(up[1], up)
up := close[1] > up1 ? math.max(up, up1) : up
dn = MA + Multiplier * atr
dn1 = nz(dn[1], dn)
dn := close[1] < dn1 ? math.min(dn, dn1) : dn
trend = 1
trend := nz(trend[1], trend)
trend := trend == -1 and close > dn1 ? 1 : trend == 1 and close < up1 ? -1 : trend
upPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? up : na, title='Up Trend', color=color.new(color.green, 100), linewidth=0, style=plot.style_linebr)
mPlot = plot(ohlc4, title='', style=plot.style_line, color=color.blue,linewidth=2)
buySignal = (open < ohlc4 and close > ohlc4) and trend == 1

//buySignal = trend == 1 and ta.crossover(close, mPlot)
plotshape(buySignal ? up : na, title='UpTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 100))
plotshape(buySignal and showsignals ? up : na, title='Buy', text='Buy', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labelup, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))
dnPlot = plot(trend == 1 ? na : dn, title='Down Trend', style=plot.style_linebr, linewidth=0, color=color.new(color.red, 100))
sellSignal = (open > ohlc4 and close < ohlc4) and trend == -1
plotshape(sellSignal ? dn : na, title='DownTrend Begins', location=location.absolute, style=shape.circle, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 100))
plotshape(sellSignal and showsignals ? dn : na, title='Sell', text='Sell', location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.tiny, color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0))

colorup = input.color(defval = color.new(color.green, 60), title = "ColorU", inline = 'color')
colordown = input.color(defval = color.new(color.red, 60), title = "ColorD", inline = 'color')
longFillColor = highlighting ? trend == 1 ? colorup : color.white : color.new(color.white, 100)
shortFillColor = highlighting ? trend == -1 ? colordown : color.white : color.new(color.white, 100)
fill(mPlot, upPlot, title='UpTrend Highligter', color=longFillColor)
fill(mPlot, dnPlot, title='DownTrend Highligter', color=shortFillColor)
alertcondition(buySignal, title='SuperTrend Buy', message='SuperTrend Buy!')
alertcondition(sellSignal, title='SuperTrend Sell', message='SuperTrend Sell!')
changeCond = trend != trend[1]
alertcondition(changeCond, title='SuperTrend Direction Change', message='SuperTrend has changed direction!')

Also see screenshot showing arrows not coming properly as I am expecting.
Screenshot showing arrows and indicator settings
I have tried to change Buy and Sell conditions as, I want buy when trend is UP and candle open below mPlot (Blue Line) on the chart and candle close above mPlot. and exactly opposite for Sell trend is Down and candle is open above mPlot line and close below mPlot line. I am expecting it should plot correct buy and sell arrows as per my logic.
Please help me .
Thanks in advance.
